# Firebase Blocking Function - how to authorize the request (is it Firebase that calling my function)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm doing blocking function call from Firebase, as described in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions).

However, this feature seems to require an open public HTTP cloud function, which is unfortunate.

I would love to authorize that request came from Firebase and not some 'hacker'.

I've tried looking through the source code for authorization in the library, but I can't seem to find it.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to properly authorize sender for a blocking function call that it came from Firebase or clarify any misconceptions I might have regarding this process?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reviewing the [documentation about the payload your function will receive](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd#getting_user_and_context_information).

- Firstly, you can validate that the entire payload is complete as expected.
- Secondly, you should pay extra attention to the `credential` data.  This is [AuthCredential](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/gcip-cloud-functions#auth-credential) object.  Make sure it looks correct.
- Thirdly, review the documented examples for [Accessing a user's identity provider OAuth credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd#accessing_a_users_identity_provider_oauth_credentials) and [Tracking IP addresses to monitor suspicious activity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd#tracking_ip_addresses_to_monitor_suspicious_activity) and implement whatever checks from that you think would be helpful.  If the provided ID token doesn't validate, or anything else fails unexpectedly, you can reject the request.